# stream mp4 file with ffmpeg from a specific time of video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I Want to stream a video file (.mp4) from a differnt starting time.

For **example** I want to stream `test.mkv` file from minute like `00:02:30` of `test.mkv` video.
So when I stream it to rtmp server, the video is started from `00:02:30` of movie not start.
**Note**: I don't want to wait for that long, I want to start from that moment right after i pressed enter on `ffmpeg` command, So answers like using `cronjob` are not useful.

Here is the `ffmpeg` command i'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 1 -threads 0 -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 512k -bufsize 640k -maxrate 640k -preset veryfast -profile:v baseline -tune film -acodec aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0" -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f flv rtmp://test.server.com
```

#### Note:

If you guys have any suggestions on improving `ffmpeg` commmand, also I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem the flag is `-ss` but somehow there is a little tip so it works. It should be placed before any `-i` argument to work. So simple by adding for example `-ss 150` It will start from 150 seconds from start of video. So above command will be like:

```
ffmpeg -ss 150 -i test.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 1 -threads 0 -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 512k -bufsize 640k -maxrate 640k -preset veryfast -profile:v baseline -tune film -acodec aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0" -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f flv rtmp://test.server.com
```

#### Note:

Place `-ss` before any `-i` argument.